# $K$ is compact if there exist open sets $U, V$ such that...

Tags: general-topology, compactness

So my question is: Let $K \subset X$ be a compact set. Given $x \in K^{c}$, show that exist open sets $U, V$ such that $x \in V, K \subset U$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

So I know that $K$ has a finite open subcover, that I called $U$, and that $K^{c} = X - K$ is open, so I want to call $V = K^{c}$, but I am not sure how to guarantee that $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is $X$ and the assumptions imposed on $X$?

Comment: My bet is that $X$ is a Hausdorff space.

Comment: This is false if $X$ is not Hausdorff.  The main reason why is that compact subsets of arbitrary topological spaces don't have to be closed.  For a stupid example, assume $X = \{x,y\}$ is a two element set in the indiscrete topology.  Then $K = \{y\}$ is compact, and your only choice for a nonempty open set is $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is *Hausdorff*.

Let $x \in K^c$. For each $y\in K$, by Hausdorff-ness we may find neighborhoods $U_y$ of $y$ and $V_y$ of $x$ such that $U_y \cap V_y = \emptyset$. Note that the $U_y$'s form a cover of $K$, so by compactness of $K$, there is some finite collection of points $\{y_1, \cdots, y_k\} \subset K$ such that $$K \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} U_{y_k}.$$ Set $U:= \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} U_{y_k}$ and set $V:= \bigcap_{i=1}^{k} V_{y_k}$. It is then straightforward to check $K \subset U$, $x \in V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is Hausdorff. Then for any $y\in K$ take $V_y$ and $U_y$ which are open and disjoint with $y\in V_y$, $x\in U_y$. Take a set $V$ (as you predicted) as a finite union of $V_y$, namely $V=V_{y_{1}}\cup\dots\cup V_{y_{n}}$ and $U=U_{y_{1}}\cap\dots\cap U_{y_{n}}.$